If f is absolutely integrable then f is also integrable?
My real analysis professor said:

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ is absolutely Riemann-integrable, i.e. $|f|\in\mathcal R([a,b])$ for any $a<b$, then, by definition, $f$ is Riemann-integrable, i.e. $f\in\mathcal R([a,b])$ for any $a<b$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ exists.

I don't understand why it is true. I can cook up a simple counterexample:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$} \\
-1 & \text{if $x\in(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cap[0,1]$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Your professor is wrong and your example is fine.
